# How would i go about producing a username instead of a user id in profile.php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Ok guys well to boot this up what i am wanting is to remove the echo of userid in the url and replace it with the actual username.

the full code is in the link below the partial code.

```
if(!isset($_GET["u"]) || !($u = $db->getRow("SELECT * FROM `".MLS_PREFIX."users` WHERE `userid`= ?i", $_GET["u"]))){
```

http://pastebin.com/yM5gLAkr

EXAMPLE:

CURRENT: index.php?u=1

what i want: index.php?u=username

Comment: You'll need to restructure your links and then add rewrite rule in your htaccess. Make links something like `domain.com/dir/userid/username`.

Then do a rewrite rule for `/dir/[0-9]+/` to `/user.php?id=$1`.... Oh, you updated. Okay if you don't care about parameters just change query to `username = ?` then change the links on your page to use the name rather than the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change 
    WHERE `userid`= ?i
to
    WHERE `username`= ?s

This should be enough, unless there's a bunch of other stuff using $_GET['u'].

You will also need to update every single link / form on the website that redirects with ?u=$userid.